# Wait for Google translate api before writing to excel sheet

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-translate, exceljs

I can't figure out how to make my code wait for google translate before trying to write to the excel sheet. In the console i can see the translated data but in the excel doc it is still in the original language. i know I'm doing this all wrong but I can't figure it out.

It's not shown in the code below, but at the beginning i read data from a .csv file. Get only the data i need and store it as an array of objects for each case. I then go through that array and write down each case/object to an excel file.

There is a prop called verbatim which is text i am trying to translate to english before writing it to the excel file. But it's not working.

```
  cases.push({
    caseid: row['[CALLERNO_EMAIL_SOCIAL]'],
    caseorigine: row['[CASE_ORIGINE]'],
    emailaddress: row['[EMAIL]'],
    agent: row['[AGENT]'],
    region: row['[REGION2]'],
    csat: parseInt(row['Satisfaction note'], 10),
    fcr: fcr,
    phone: row['[PHONE]'],
    sentDate: row.date_envoi.slice(0, 10),
    receivedDate: row.date_reponse.slice(0, 10),
    verbatim: row['Verbatim experience'],
    tally1: row['[TALLY_1]'],
    tally2: row['[TALLY_2]'],
  });

const filter = {
  'Email entrant': 'emailentrant',
  'Email Sortant': 'emailsortant',
  'Appel Entrant': 'appelentrant',
  'Appel Sortant': 'appelsortant',
  Chat: 'chat',
};

function filterArray(array, filter) {
  return array.filter((item) => {
    if (filters.includes(filter[item.caseorigine])) {
      if (!filters.includes('includecsat5')) {
        if (parseInt(item.csat, 10) !== 5) return item;
      } else {
        return item;
      }
    }
  });
}
const filteredCases = await filterArray(cases, filter);

// translate verbatim value to english
async function translateTextWithModel() {
  filteredCases.forEach(async (item) => {
    const options = {
      to: target,
      model: model,
    };
    if (item.verbatim !== '') {
      let [verbatim] = await translate.translate(item.verbatim, options);
      console.log(verbatim);
      item.verbatim = verbatim;
    }
  });
}

await translateTextWithModel();

// write data to excel
filteredCases.forEach(async (item) => {
  worksheet.getRow(rowNum).getCell(1).value = item.caseid;
  worksheet.getRow(rowNum).getCell(2).value = item.caseorigine;
  worksheet.getRow(rowNum).getCell(3).value = item.emailaddress;
  worksheet.getRow(rowNum).getCell(4).value = item.agent;
  worksheet.getRow(rowNum).getCell(5).value = item.region;
  worksheet.getRow(rowNum).getCell(6).value = item.csat;
  worksheet.getRow(rowNum).getCell(7).value = item.fcr;
  worksheet.getRow(rowNum).getCell(8).value = item.phone;
  worksheet.getRow(rowNum).getCell(9).value = item.sentDate;
  worksheet.getRow(rowNum).getCell(10).value = item.receivedDate;
  worksheet.getRow(rowNum).getCell(11).value = item.verbatim;
  worksheet.getRow(rowNum).getCell(12).value = item.tally1;
  worksheet.getRow(rowNum).getCell(13).value = item.tally2;
  worksheet.getRow(rowNum).commit();
  rowNum += 1;
});

const outFile = `${destination}/${shortid.generate()}.xlsx`;

await workbook.xlsx.writeFile(outFile).then(async function () {
  const file = new File({
    title,
    description,
    file_path: outFile,
    file_mimetype: mimetype,
  });
  await file.save().then(res.send('file uploaded successfully.'));
});
```

Comment: If you can confirm that the translated text is printed (e.g. with `console.log(verbatim)`), it seems to me that the translated text is being lost before reaching the excel instructions. Don't you think that `let` in `let [verbatim]` is causing the values disappear? as far as I know the scope of `let` is to the immediate enclosing block `{` `}`, what's the result of using a global variable with `var` or at least at the same level of the array definition?

Comment: it made no difference with var. The console.log in the translation function shows that the text is being translated correctly. The issue is that the excel part is running before the function has time to finish. I added another console.log outside the translate function to check the verbatim in the array and it prints the untranslated text and then the function will print its text. I can't figure out how to make the code run the translation first.

Comment: I replaced the translation part with a simple code to replace the verbatim part with 'test' and that worked. So the issue is really that the rest of the code runs first and doesn't wait for the translation

Comment: i fixed it by using a module called p-iteration. While it works fine now, i would still like to know how i could have made it work the vanilla way

Comment: I only can think of the nature of NodeJS that [eliminates the waiting](https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_intro.asp), and simply continues with the next request, maybe if the excel statements are included in a function you can get different results, but not totally sure. Could you post how the behavior was resolved? the details can help others with same issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it using a module called p-iteration

```
const { forEach } = require('p-iteration');


  await forEach(filteredCases, async (item) => {
          async function translateTextWithModel(text) {
            const options = {
              to: 'en',
              model: 'nmt',
            };
            if (text !== '') {
              var [verbatim] = await translate.translate(text, options);
              return verbatim;
            }
          }
          item.verbatim = await translateTextWithModel(item.verbatim);
          worksheet.getRow(rowNum).getCell(1).value = item.caseid;
          worksheet.getRow(rowNum).getCell(2).value = item.caseorigine;
          worksheet.getRow(rowNum).getCell(3).value = item.emailaddress;
          worksheet.getRow(rowNum).getCell(4).value = item.agent;
          worksheet.getRow(rowNum).getCell(5).value = item.region;
          worksheet.getRow(rowNum).getCell(6).value = item.csat;
          worksheet.getRow(rowNum).getCell(7).value = item.fcr;
          worksheet.getRow(rowNum).getCell(8).value = item.phone;
          worksheet.getRow(rowNum).getCell(9).value = item.sentDate;
          worksheet.getRow(rowNum).getCell(10).value = item.receivedDate;
          worksheet.getRow(rowNum).getCell(11).value = item.verbatim;
          worksheet.getRow(rowNum).getCell(12).value = item.tally1;
          worksheet.getRow(rowNum).getCell(13).value = item.tally2;
          worksheet.getRow(rowNum).commit();
          rowNum += 1;
        });
```